# How to use CUDA to transcode video files in Linux

Tags: linux, cuda, transcode

Now I'm looking for methods to accelerate transcode process in Linux. At this moment, I'm looking into CUDA and successfully compile the driver and SDK things in Linux. However, I can't step forward because NOT any software or toolkit in the field of transcode supports CUDA in Linux.

Any sugguestion or comments are welcome. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV open computer vision library was gpu CUDA optimised module that contains functionality to encode and decode video files. [OpenCV repo](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/repository/show/trunk/opencv/modules/gpu/)